# Is there a way to use the TensorFlow dataset interface with TFGAN?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The gan_model function [expects a tensor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/17103a0b8dfdd7abd2b0dcb14f905aba879ff3a4/tensorflow/contrib/gan/python/train.py#L112) (or something convertible to a tensor) as its input, is there a straightforward way to modify it so that I can pass a dataset iterator?

edit: It will work if i feed the images in as:

```
tf.Session() as sess:
    images = sess.run(iterator.get_next())
```

but in this case it wont evaluate the get_next for every batch

it wont work if I feed:

```
images = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: You should probably pass the output of `iterator.get_next()` instead. What happens when you try to do that?

Comment: It works if I pass a tensor but if I pass iterator.get_next(), which has type  Tensor("inputs/IteratorGetNext:0", dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0), then i get the error: Input 0 of layer conv2d_1 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined. Am I doing something obviously wrong here?